# ReactiveElasticsearchRepository not auto indexing on startup

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-data-elasticsearch

In nonreactive ElasticsearchRepository, there's a class AbstractElasticsearchRepository that does

```
    try {
            if (createIndexAndMapping()) {
                createIndex();
                putMapping();
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            LOGGER.warn("Cannot create index: {}", exception.getMessage());
        }
```

Is there a different, more manual, setup for ReactiveElasticsearchRepository? My index mapping only gets created when creating a record and not on startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reactive repositories this is implemented in 4.1.0-M1, so it will be available in the next release (or when using the milestone).

If you cannot switch to the milestone version, you will need to create a non-reactive client as well and do the createIndex and putMapping with this client.

Comment: Awesome! I'll switch the milestone for now and test it out. I was also noticing that the mapping that was created when you create a record was not adhering to the @Setting on my entity class. I'm assuming switching to the milestone version and having it index on start will fix that problem?

Comment: Using the milestone fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: `@Setting` is evaluated in the `createIndex()` method, so it will be applied. In the next milestone - 4.1.0-M2 there will be index template support, but that's ot out yet.